# how to do auto fetch in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection of models I fetch from a `REST API` every 10 seconds. (`collection.fetch()` every 10 seconds with a timer).

The user can also edit the model in a dialog box and click Save going back to the table of models.

How do I prevent cases where the user saves a model in a dialog and the auto fetch exactly comes back with a stale model so the model stays with the stale data until the next auto fetch.

Comment: _.debounce(function, wait)  -> When you click save you can call the same function again, but since it's debounced, it must wait at least another time period before it can be hit again by another function call

Comment: You can also try pausing the timer when the model is active and resume again when inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Use `collection.fetch({ update: true })` - that way models will only be add/remove/change'd rather than recreated on each fetch.
2. When the model is edited via the your dialog box, only `save()` the specific attributes that the user changed, like `model.save(changedData, { patch: true });` -- using this patch behavior will make sure you're only sending the attributes that were just changed. Then your server can respond with the other recently-changed attributes, and all should be fine.